# Small, spikey plant, maybe in the aloe family?

Tags: identification, aloe

[image]

I do not know what this plant is - does anyone have any guesses? :)

Comment: Young Dracena? I can't tel if the leaves are thin or fat. Are the serrated edges a photo artifact, or are they there?